# Add files to Ubuntu Desktop disk image

Tags: live-cd, livedvd

I would like to create an Ubuntu 14.04 disk, with some extra files on the desktop - for instance, some HTML files with instructions for some project.

What's the right way to edit the ISO file and add files to the Desktop, that would be available when booted as a live CD?

I am using a DVD media, so size is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ubuntu Customization Kit, Ubuntu Builder, Customizer or possibly other tools to remaster the ISO and add the software/configurations you want, building your own Ubuntu based LiveCD.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to edit the ISO directly?